# Test Case passed but coverage report showing 0% with --cover-inclusive argument to nosetests command and tox

Tags: code-coverage, nose, tox

I am executing test cases with tox with nosetests and coverage. I am using the command as "nosetests -v --with-xunit --xunit-file=nosetests.xml --cover-inclusive"

without --cover-inclusive argument coverage report shows actual coverage percentage. But with --cover-inclusive coverage report shows 0% with some modules.

SO how can I discover the holes in test coverage. Can anyone suggest me?

I am not getting any error about the above.Only coverage report shows 0%.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the additional options

```
--cover-html --cover-html-dir=DIR
```

to to to figure out what is being tested and where the holes are. Remember that `--with-coverage` is always a required parameter to generate coverage.